# Bootstrap with navbar logo

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

it is different question from other questions. because in this question sidebar wrap out to the logo. 
i want to use logo in my page. but when i use it. it will not fit on the screen. The side bar covers the logo on desktop. the screen shot is attach also[image: this is the result on desktop]. 
Just half off logo is shown. 
but when i open this page in my mobile. it looks good.

```
   <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" role="navigation" style="margin-bottom: 0">
        <div class="navbar-header">
             <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
             </button>
            <a  href="index.php"  class="navbar-left"><img src="logo.jpg" alt=""></a>
        </div>
        <!-- /.navbar-header -->

        <ul class="nav navbar-top-links navbar-right">

            <!-- /.dropdown -->

            <li class="dropdown">
                <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                    <i class="fa fa-user fa-fw"></i> <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-user">
                    <li><a href="add_user.php"><i class="fa fa-user fa-fw"></i> Add User</a>
                    </li>

                </ul>
                <!-- /.dropdown-user -->
            </li>
            <!-- /.dropdown -->
        </ul>
        <!-- /.navbar-top-links -->

        <div class="navbar-default sidebar" role="navigation">
            <div class="sidebar-nav navbar-collapse">
                <ul class="nav" id="side-menu">

                    <li>
                        <a href="index.php"><i class="fa fa-dashboard fa-fw"></i> Dashboard</a>
                    </li>

                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- /.sidebar-collapse -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.navbar-static-side -->
    </nav>
```

please help me how to fit this image? thanks

Comment: <img src="logo.jpg" alt=""> Specify height and width attributes of img tag and then try.

Comment: not working. #Rahi

Comment: Try taking it outside of <a> tag.

Comment: not working again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

in the markup

```
<img class="img-responsive logo" src="logo.jpg" alt="">
```

and in the css

```
.logo {max-width:150px; /* Adjust accordingly */ }
```

and add padding/margin to the sidebar.

Comment: really helpfull. thanks